async setState in react not effect
I have a app.jsx, which will request two different api named API_A & API_B. I will get data_A and data_B from this two api and merge them into a info state for render ui. My code is like this:
  const [info, setInfo] = useState();

  function go(){
    API_A().then(({ data }) => {
      setInfo((prev) => {
        const t = {
          ...prev,
          ...data,
        };
        console.log('===== set API_A ====', t);
        // for deep clone, in real condition res is a object
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(t));
      });
    });
    API_B().then(({ data: res = {} }) => {
      setInfo(prev => {
        
        const t = {
          ...prev,
          ...res,
        };
        console.log('===== set API_B ====', t);
        // for deep clone, in real condition res is a object
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(t));
      });
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    go();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('=====useEffect info', info); 
  }, [info]

the console result like this image. useEffect info not been triggered. It didn't set data_B into info successfully.
console result image
I dont know why data_B havent been set into info. It looks like setState has been executed but not been set successfuly.
react version: 17.0.48

I would take a different approach to this. As you have two API calls that eventually will update one state, I would use Promise.all so that i would execute the setInfo once both APIs are done. Also, with the approach you have mentioned, the component will re-render twice whereas with the below it will re-render once.
Thus I would modify the code to the below:
const [info, setInfo] = useState();

function go() {
  Promise.all([API_A(), API_B()]).then(([responseA, responseB]) => {
    setInfo(prev => {
      const t = {
        ...prev,
        ...responseA.data,
        ...responseB.data,
      };
      console.log('===== set API_A and API_B ====', t);
      return t;
    });
  });
}

useEffect(() => {
  go();
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('=====useEffect info', info);
}, [info])

